# Removing all punctuation from a list and return the entire list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list that I'm trying to strip all punctuation and the character "·" from and then returning that list without any of the above. However, when I try to return the list, only the first word of the list appears and I'm not sure where I went wrong with this.

Here is the list I'm trying to strip punctuation from: 
['in·vis·i·ble', 'in·vis·i·bil·i·ty, ', 'in·vis·i·ble·ness, ', 'in·vis·i·bly, ', 'qua·si-in·vis·i·ble, ', 'qua·si-in·vis·i·bly, ', 'inˌvisiˈbility, ', 'inˈvisibleness, ', 'inˈvisibly, ']

Here's what I'm getting: ['invisible']

Here is a portion of my code (it's part of a larger function)

```
syl = []
for words in span:
    if words not in syl:
        syl.append(words)
for text in syl:
    drop_sep = re.sub(r'·', '', text)
    return drop_sep
```

Comment: What is `·`? Is it a period?

Comment: It's a separator used to separate syllables. It's used on dictionary.com

Comment: If you put a return in a loop, the loop runs only once obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) where each element of the resulting list is a string with all occurrences of dot substring `'·'` [`replaced`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) by the *void* `''`:

```
[word.replace('·', '') for word in words]
```

**Example**

```
>>> words = ['in·vis·i·ble',
...          'in·vis·i·bil·i·ty, ',
...          'in·vis·i·ble·ness, ',
...          'in·vis·i·bly, ',
...          'qua·si-in·vis·i·ble, ',
...          'qua·si-in·vis·i·bly, ',
...          'inˌvisiˈbility, ',
...          'inˈvisibleness, ',
...          'inˈvisibly, ']
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint([word.replace('·', '') for word in words])
['invisible',
 'invisibility, ',
 'invisibleness, ',
 'invisibly, ',
 'quasi-invisible, ',
 'quasi-invisibly, ',
 'inˌvisiˈbility, ',
 'inˈvisibleness, ',
 'inˈvisibly, ']
```

Comment: He wants to keep the dash

Comment: Thank you so much!